# Uninitialized string offset with Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to run a dabatase query on an array of fields from a single form but I keep getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> ```
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 1
>
> Filename: controllers/admin.php
>
> Line Number: 259
> ```

I can't figure out what's causing it, code below:

View:

```
<input class="Form_Input" name="stock_level[]" id="stock_level[]"  value="<? echo $product['current_stock']; ?>" style="width: 30px;" />
<input class="Form_Input" name="product_id[]" id="product_id[]"  value="<? echo $product['id']; ?>"  />
<input class="Form_Input" name="batch_id[]" id="batch_id[]" type="hidden" />
```

Controller:

```
$keys = $this->input->post('stock_level', TRUE);
$product_id = $this->input->post('product_id', TRUE);
$batch_id = $this->input->post('batch_id', TRUE);
$result = array();

foreach ($keys as $id => $key)
{
 $result[$key] = array(  
'stock_level' => $keys[$id],
'product_id' => $product_id[$id]
);

$stock_level = $result[$key]['stock_level'];
$product_id = $result[$key]['product_id'];

$this->admin_model->update_stock_level($product_id, $stock_level);
```

Comment: try `<?php var_dump($this->input->post(NULL));?>` to see Your POST-vars. I think You should use not `->post('stock_level', TRUE);` but `->post('stock_level[]', TRUE);`

Comment: what is in line number 259?

Comment: Tried using `>post('stock_level[]', TRUE);` but I get an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error.

Comment: Line 259 is `'stock_level' => $keys[$id],`

Comment: I don't understand this error. I have the exact same code on another site that works perfectly. It's driving my crazy!